# Typescript automatically figure what is the type base on the if statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a function with the following signature.

```
function doSomething(bool = false): number | string {
    if (bool) {
        return '1';
    } else {
        return 1;
   }
}

const value = doSomething();

const valueTwo = doSomething(true);
```

My issue is that the `type` of the `value` variable is `number | string` in both cases. How can I tell typescript to return the correct type based on the if block without doing something like that:

```
const value = doSomething() as number;

const valueTwo = doSomething(true) as string;
```

Comment: You can explicitly type your values (`const value: number = ..., const valueTwo: string = ...`), but that's no different from what you're doing already

Comment: Bear in mind that your `bool` doesn't have a value until runtime, by which point it's obviously too late to throw a compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple signatures for a function, and if the return type is dependent on primitive values you can use literal types to discriminate. In your case you could write:

```
// Public sigantures 
function doSomething(bool?: false): number // With false constant
function doSomething(bool: true): string // With true constant or missing
function doSomething(bool?: boolean): number | string // With unknown bool value 
// Implementation siganture
function doSomething(bool: boolean = false): number | string {
    if (bool) {
        return '1';
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
var s = doSomething(true) // s is string
var n2 = doSomething() // n2 is number
var n3 = doSomething(false) // n3 is number
declare var b: boolean;
var ns4 = doSomething(b) // ns4 is string | number because it can't be determined at compile time
```

Comment: what about the number?

Comment: @undefined sorry , it was a typo `n3` is number

Comment: So I should explicitly set the false? Can't I set a default value of false like in my example?

Comment: @undefined Wops, I missed the default, I added, aslo the behavior was off in that case `doSomething()`  will be number

Comment: If the boolean was a function how would I know if he passes the function or not?

Comment: With function you can't discriminate by value, you can discriminate if the value was passed or not, just have a public signature with the parameter and one without.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is a statically typed langauge - at compile time it understands the type definitions you have in your code and can help find errors by checking that you're not getting types crossed.

When you mark a method as having the return `number | string`, you're giving the compiler information: **you know the method will return one of these two possible types**. The compiler doesn't have the ability to look at the method in detail to understand the conditions under which your code will return a particular type. This is why we have to tell the compiler all the possible return types in our method signatures; it can't figure it out for itself.

If you want the compiler to know the types, you can give it more information using overload signatures which discriminate a return type based on some constant values:

```
function doSomething(bool: false): number
function doSomething(bool?: true): string
function doSomething(bool?: boolean): number | string
```

The compiler can now resolve the return type based on the value of the boolean, but **it will only do so if the value is a constant**: one which is known at compile-time.

This means that these statements have a known single return type:

```
var str = doSomething(true);
var bool = doSomething(false);
```

But this invocation does not:

```
declare var input: boolean;
var strOrBool = doSomething(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but:

- If you're referring to when you manually pass in a literal, [that would likely be a bad design; you're trying to have the function do too much](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior). In this case, just break it into two function with different return types. Both can even rely on a third function that encapsulates the common behavior between the two. To answer the question though, in this case, I don't know of any way to do that. That's a complicated inference to have the compiler make.
- If you want it to be able to figure out the type for any arbitrary data passed in, that would be impossible. If you give it user-supplied data at run-time, it's impossible for it to be able to infer the type at compile-time. You're asking it to make decisions based on information that it doesn't have.

Comment: Actually it pretty much is common practice in TS to discriminate return type based on string constants just look at jQuery plugins, you have one function, that takes a `string` parameter which basically selects the overload which will be used for type checking and determins the rest of the parameters as well as return type

Comment: Random example from select2: `interface Select2Plugin {(method: 'val', value: any, triggerChange?: boolean): any;(method: 'close'): JQuery;` https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/924fafffc09cfeb0267573af2c847cdbfcfa464d/types/select2/index.d.ts

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Maybe, but I wouldn't say that that's reason to not label it as poor-practice. That seems to be a convenience/design trade-off, which is a slippery slope.